# Would 256 Bytes be Enough for a Gamesave Storage Chip on a Cartridge?

Tags: load, byte, storage, capacity

It might be possible that I'm going make a game console in the far future, and of course, I'll need to know enough about that in order to start. So I was wondering, since technically a saved game state could be a very small command that the console recognizes as a large action (theoretically), such as "Load", and then the game would load from a certain part of the game, would 256 bytes be enough data for a gamesave cartridge storage chip? I'm assuming it is, but for those of you who have greater knowledge about this stuff, feel free to throw in your answers.

Comment: Uh, make a game console? Well, what are we talking about? If it's not roughly NES era, you're going to want more than 256 bytes for save space.

Comment: Well, technically, if the gamesave data is stored in a very simple form, the console can interpret it as other things, so to me, it seems like enough, but I might take your advice if I find that I'm having difficulty with 256 bytes. Plus, I suppose I should mention that the gamesave data is stored on the cartridge. Each cartridge would have its own 256 bytes, and the console would have 1 terabyte of storage, in case the gamesave data gets lost. The ROM however, where the game is stored, is going to be 8 GB.

Comment: 256 bytes of save space compared to EIGHT GIGS of ROM? Hah, what. First of all, if you make a game that somehow requires _eight gigabytes_, odds are you need to save more than 256 bytes of player data. Especially if you want to save things like specific location, world state, a detailed inventory, active enemies, etc. This seems very silly, honestly. If you can afford an eight gig cartridge and write ROM to it, you can afford a few megabytes of save data.

Comment: I guess I didn't consider active enemies and such, maybe 512 bytes might make more sense, or possibly 2 KB, or maybe even 256 KB, I don't know. That just seems like too much, especially if that coding could just as easily be stored in a low-level format and be read and expanded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

256 bytes would be enough only for the most rudimentary of games.

For an 8 Gb game I would say having 8 Mb of save would be a plausible minimum.

Comment: Yeah, maybe the more complex games could have more, like 2 KB. That would allow up to 2048 characters of text, therefore, it would be a lot easier to save long lines of code. I'm planning on having everything just saved onto the gamesave chip as low-level text, which can be read and interpreted as whatever areas or coordinates in the game need to be accessed. I guess 256 bytes is only 256 characters of text, and that would limit many factors.

Comment: Added estimate of a minimum for a game of the scope allowed by the rom.

Comment: Maybe it could kind of be stored like "player x=3.5 player y=4.6". That's just an example, of course, but that's kind of the direction I was going, and I didn't think that much text was needed in such small, low-level scripting.

Comment: For simple games it is possible, but modern console games often go above 20 Mb of save. That's per save file. Many games allow you to make multiple saves also, both within the game and for multiple users.

Comment: Well, I can see that in a game where you can save pictures and footage, such as Super Smash Bros. Brawl. However, I don't believe any of the games that I'm doing will have features like that, and if they do, that all just goes to the hard drive.

Comment: Given the options of using the hard-drive with no limitations and a tiny space on a cartridge I don't see the advantage of using the cartridge. Maybe for bringing a character to visit a friend or something. If you are clear about the intended use of the cartridge ram in this or similar fashion the small space would be justifiable.

Comment: Well, the cartridge is, like you said, in case you want to see a friend and not start from the beginning, and also to back up the HDD, in the unlikely event of a hard drive failure. However, I'm choosing to use cartridges for various other reasons; 1, the game sizes usually aren't as large, because they are stored on ROM, and the capacity on ROM is usually limited, and they are also expensive. However, this would allow for hardware add-ons and co-processors to assist the system and boost capability during run-time. 2, cartridges are durable. There's enough videos to prove that. 3, The game...

Comment: ...data can be saved on the cartridge, as mentioned, which personally, I like to be able to not have to start the game over every time I play on another console. 4, cartridges have extremely fast loading times, because the ROM can be read directly like RAM.